# Как сделать исчезающую FAB?

Tags: java, android, xml

Имеется ListView и FAB. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке списка вниз FAB исчезала, а при прокрутке вверх появлялась? Только не предлагайте использовать RecyclerView, мне нужен вариант с имеющимися элементами.

Comment: Поместите список и FAB внутрь CoordinatorLayout и задайте для FAB floatingActionButtonBehaviour - просто скопипастить код этого класса из сети. Либо повесьте слушатель скрола на ListView и прячьте вручную

Comment: FAB в CoordinatorLayout работать будет только с recyclerView. С ListView не работает вроде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте CoordinatorLayout, это самый лучший способ по данной задаче

Вот вам [пример](https://github.com/febaisi/FABHideListView) где Fab скрывается по скроллу ListView